# print the alphabets with their occurrence in perl using regex

Tags: regex, perl

Implement a method to perform string compression using the counts of repeated characters. For Example aabcccccaaaaaaa would become a2b1c5a7. Decompress the string to the original string.

I tried below code but looking for some one liner regex solution -

```
sub print_word{
   my $s=shift;
   my @a=split(//, $s);
   my $c=1;
   my $r='';

   my $t=$a[0];
   for( my $i=1; $i<=$#a; $i++) {
       if($t eq $a[$i]) {
           $c++;
       }else{
           $r.=$t."$c";
           $t=$a[$i];
           $c=1;
       }
   }  
   $r.=$t."$c";
   return $r;
}
print print_word('aabcccccaaaaaaa') . "\n";
```

Kindly provide something using regex in one line.

Comment: What is the source of your 'one liner/regex' constraint?

Comment: I did not understand you question?
I wants to do this using regex, though i am also trying the same myself.

Comment: Regular expressions aren't actually all that good a solution to this particular problem, which is why I'm asking. regex looks compact and 'neat' but it can be quite inefficient.

Comment: Actually I solved this problem using simple logic with array and hash. As it is also achievable by regex so i tried my hands on regex too. By not able to get the expected answer. So, do not worry about the performance or complexity, just want to solve it using regex. Thanks Sobrique for your reply.

Comment: OK. In which case I'll have a crack at it. But bear in mind, it's still probably not going to be the most efficient solution to the problem. Regular expressions do comeplx things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fairly straightforward if you use an *expression* substitution with the `/e` modifier. That allows you to put a Perl expression in the *replacement* part of the `s///` operator instead of a simple string

Here's a demonstration

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my $s = 'aabcccccaaaaaaa';
say $s;

(my $encoded = $s) =~ s/(([a-z])\g2*)/$2.length $1/egi;
say $encoded;

(my $decoded = $encoded) =~ s/([a-z])(\d+)/$1 x $2/egi;
say $decoded;

say $s eq $decoded ? 'Match okay' : 'Round trip failed';
```

#### output

```
aabcccccaaaaaaa
a2b1c5a7
aabcccccaaaaaaa
Match okay
```

Answer (score 6):

OK, so the trick here is - matching back references with your string;

```
my $string = 'aabcccccaaaaaaa';

$string =~ s/((\w)\2*)/ "$2". length ($1) /eg;
print $string;
```

This gives:

```
a2b1c5a7
```

We 'capture' a word character (`\w`), and we use `\2*` to refer to zero or more (so making it 'one more more' because of the first letter).

And then we encapsulate *that* in another capture group, which means we have `\2` or `$2` as our single letter, and `\1` or `$1` as the substring of the same letter.

We print `$2` and then - because we have the `e` flag set on the regex - it evaluates `length ( $1 )` and inserts that.

To expand what I said on efficiency - we need to go to a code profiler.

Using something like `Devel::NYTProf`:

```
perl -d:NYTProf script.pl
nytprofhtml --open
```

Your code as written:

[image: Your loop]

My example

[image: My Example]

Now, there are scale questions here - I mean, if you run repeatedly, you may find the regex solution starts to "win". There's an overhead for using regular expressions at all, and *certain* regular expressions can be exceedingly 'expensive'. See for example: http://blog.codinghorror.com/regex-performance/

Try the same test - for example - running both in a loop 100,000 times, the numbers start to even out.

Mine:

[image: Regex x 100,000]

Yours:

[image: Yours x 100,000]

But I'd suggest still - don't worry about performance until you're sure you need to. Until then, go with whatever is the easiest to read and understand.

I wasn't sure until I ran what the outcome would about [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html) in response to another question, which is why 'be careful with regexes' was high in my mind.

They look neat, and they are clever, but sometimes they're a bit *too* clever. But in this case, that doesn't really seem to apply. There's an overhead for the regex engine, but once it's started 'works' and runs quite nicely.

One of the useful tricks for figuring out 'how clever' a regex is you can `use re 'debug';`

With my example, this prints:

```
Compiling REx "((\w)\2*)"
Final program:
   1: OPEN1 (3)
   3:   OPEN2 (5)
   5:     POSIXD[\w] (6)
   6:   CLOSE2 (8)
   8:   CURLYX[2] {0,32767} (13)
  10:     REF2 (12)
  12:   WHILEM[1/1] (0)
  13:   NOTHING (14)
  14: CLOSE1 (16)
  16: END (0)
stclass POSIXD[\w] minlen 1 
Matching REx "((\w)\2*)" against "aabcccccaaaaaaa"
Matching stclass POSIXD[\w] against "aabcccccaaaaaaa" (15 bytes)
   0 <> <aabcccccaa>         |  1:OPEN1(3)
   0 <> <aabcccccaa>         |  3:OPEN2(5)
   0 <> <aabcccccaa>         |  5:POSIXD[\w](6)
   1 <a> <abcccccaaa>        |  6:CLOSE2(8)
   1 <a> <abcccccaaa>        |  8:CURLYX[2] {0,32767}(13)
   1 <a> <abcccccaaa>        | 12:  WHILEM[1/1](0)
                                    whilem: matched 0 out of 0..32767
   1 <a> <abcccccaaa>        | 10:    REF2: "a"(12)
   2 <aa> <bcccccaaaa>       | 12:    WHILEM[1/1](0)
                                      whilem: matched 1 out of 0..32767
   2 <aa> <bcccccaaaa>       | 10:      REF2: "a"(12)
                                        failed...
                                      whilem: failed, trying continuation...
   2 <aa> <bcccccaaaa>       | 13:      NOTHING(14)
   2 <aa> <bcccccaaaa>       | 14:      CLOSE1(16)
   2 <aa> <bcccccaaaa>       | 16:      END(0)
Match successful!
Matching REx "((\w)\2*)" against "bcccccaaaaaaa"
Matching stclass POSIXD[\w] against "bcccccaaaaaaa" (13 bytes)
   2 <aa> <bcccccaaaa>       |  1:OPEN1(3)
   2 <aa> <bcccccaaaa>       |  3:OPEN2(5)
   2 <aa> <bcccccaaaa>       |  5:POSIXD[\w](6)
   3 <aab> <cccccaaaaa>      |  6:CLOSE2(8)
   3 <aab> <cccccaaaaa>      |  8:CURLYX[2] {0,32767}(13)
   3 <aab> <cccccaaaaa>      | 12:  WHILEM[1/1](0)
                                    whilem: matched 0 out of 0..32767
   3 <aab> <cccccaaaaa>      | 10:    REF2: "b"(12)
                                      failed...
                                    whilem: failed, trying continuation...
   3 <aab> <cccccaaaaa>      | 13:    NOTHING(14)
   3 <aab> <cccccaaaaa>      | 14:    CLOSE1(16)
   3 <aab> <cccccaaaaa>      | 16:    END(0)
Match successful!
Matching REx "((\w)\2*)" against "cccccaaaaaaa"
Matching stclass POSIXD[\w] against "cccccaaaaaaa" (12 bytes)
   3 <aab> <cccccaaaaa>      |  1:OPEN1(3)
   3 <aab> <cccccaaaaa>      |  3:OPEN2(5)
   3 <aab> <cccccaaaaa>      |  5:POSIXD[\w](6)
   4 <aabc> <ccccaaaaaa>     |  6:CLOSE2(8)
   4 <aabc> <ccccaaaaaa>     |  8:CURLYX[2] {0,32767}(13)
   4 <aabc> <ccccaaaaaa>     | 12:  WHILEM[1/1](0)
                                    whilem: matched 0 out of 0..32767
   4 <aabc> <ccccaaaaaa>     | 10:    REF2: "c"(12)
   5 <aabcc> <cccaaaaaaa>    | 12:    WHILEM[1/1](0)
                                      whilem: matched 1 out of 0..32767
   5 <aabcc> <cccaaaaaaa>    | 10:      REF2: "c"(12)
   6 <abccc> <ccaaaaaaa>     | 12:      WHILEM[1/1](0)
                                        whilem: matched 2 out of 0..32767
   6 <abccc> <ccaaaaaaa>     | 10:        REF2: "c"(12)
   7 <bcccc> <caaaaaaa>      | 12:        WHILEM[1/1](0)
                                          whilem: matched 3 out of 0..32767
   7 <bcccc> <caaaaaaa>      | 10:          REF2: "c"(12)
   8 <ccccc> <aaaaaaa>       | 12:          WHILEM[1/1](0)
                                            whilem: matched 4 out of 0..32767
   8 <ccccc> <aaaaaaa>       | 10:            REF2: "c"(12)
                                              failed...
                                            whilem: failed, trying continuation...
   8 <ccccc> <aaaaaaa>       | 13:            NOTHING(14)
   8 <ccccc> <aaaaaaa>       | 14:            CLOSE1(16)
   8 <ccccc> <aaaaaaa>       | 16:            END(0)
Match successful!
Matching REx "((\w)\2*)" against "aaaaaaa"
Matching stclass POSIXD[\w] against "aaaaaaa" (7 bytes)
   8 <ccccc> <aaaaaaa>       |  1:OPEN1(3)
   8 <ccccc> <aaaaaaa>       |  3:OPEN2(5)
   8 <ccccc> <aaaaaaa>       |  5:POSIXD[\w](6)
   9 <ccccca> <aaaaaa>       |  6:CLOSE2(8)
   9 <ccccca> <aaaaaa>       |  8:CURLYX[2] {0,32767}(13)
   9 <ccccca> <aaaaaa>       | 12:  WHILEM[1/1](0)
                                    whilem: matched 0 out of 0..32767
   9 <ccccca> <aaaaaa>       | 10:    REF2: "a"(12)
  10 <cccccaa> <aaaaa>       | 12:    WHILEM[1/1](0)
                                      whilem: matched 1 out of 0..32767
  10 <cccccaa> <aaaaa>       | 10:      REF2: "a"(12)
  11 <cccccaaa> <aaaa>       | 12:      WHILEM[1/1](0)
                                        whilem: matched 2 out of 0..32767
  11 <cccccaaa> <aaaa>       | 10:        REF2: "a"(12)
  12 <cccccaaaa> <aaa>       | 12:        WHILEM[1/1](0)
                                          whilem: matched 3 out of 0..32767
  12 <cccccaaaa> <aaa>       | 10:          REF2: "a"(12)
  13 <cccccaaaaa> <aa>       | 12:          WHILEM[1/1](0)
                                            whilem: matched 4 out of 0..32767
  13 <cccccaaaaa> <aa>       | 10:            REF2: "a"(12)
  14 <cccccaaaaaa> <a>       | 12:            WHILEM[1/1](0)
                                              whilem: matched 5 out of 0..32767
  14 <cccccaaaaaa> <a>       | 10:              REF2: "a"(12)
  15 <cccccaaaaaaa> <>       | 12:              WHILEM[1/1](0)
                                                whilem: matched 6 out of 0..32767
  15 <cccccaaaaaaa> <>       | 10:                REF2: "a"(12)
                                                  failed...
                                                whilem: failed, trying continuation...
  15 <cccccaaaaaaa> <>       | 13:                NOTHING(14)
  15 <cccccaaaaaaa> <>       | 14:                CLOSE1(16)
  15 <cccccaaaaaaa> <>       | 16:                END(0)
Match successful!
Matching REx "((\w)\2*)" against ""
Regex match can't succeed, so not even tried
Freeing REx: "((\w)\2*)"
```

So as you can see, it's actually doing quite a lot of work in this example. But as it's not having to backtrack at any point to match your strings, it's not really *wasting* any effort particularly either.

Comment: wow, weirdly similar solutions. I guess not that weird since this is a reasonable way to do this.

Comment: `\2*` actually makes the string `abcdef` twice as long converting it to `a1b1c1d1e1f1`, should probably change to `\2+`.

Comment: Solution seems too magical. Thanks Sobrique.
As you said using regex can be inefficient so could you provide reasoning behind that?

Comment: Yes. Basically regular expressions are a programming language in their own right. The 'code' is the regular expression - it compiles the code, runs it, generates the result. It can be quite efficient at it, but in some cases it has to do some complex operations to decide if it's matching the right thing. http://blog.codinghorror.com/regex-performance/

Comment: Have also dug out a couple of useful tricks. `use re 'debug';` is quite neat.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen - `\2+` doesn't match against the original text in the same way though.

Comment: @Sobrique in what way?